# CodeIgniter: Unable to update a record in database, not showing any errors

Tags: database, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to update a record in my database, It is a reservation that the user can update some or all of the fields and after I press submit it redirects me to the page I need but no changes happen in the database.

Model

```
       public function res_form_input(){

            $newDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->input->post('re_date')));
            $newTime = date("H:i", strtotime($this->input->post('re_time')));
            $data = array(

                'num' => $this->input->post('num'),
                'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
                'diners' => $this->input->post('diners'),
                're_date' => $newDate,
                're_time' => $newTime,
                'phonenumber' => $this->input->post('phonenumber'),
                'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),  

            );

            return $data;
        }
        public function update_res($id){

           $data = $this->res_form_input();
//           $this->db->set('$data');
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('tables', $data);

        }
```

Controller

```
public function edit() {

        echo $id = $this->session->flashdata('reservation_id');
        $this->Hosting_model->update_res($id);
        redirect(base_url("/hosting/tableMap"));

    }
```

Comment: did you load the model?

Comment: Of course, I have many more functions that work perfectly including the insert

Comment: does this `$this->session->flashdata('reservation_id');` has a value? @Victoria'sSecret

Comment: add the "$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);" and print the executed query to check final query and debug print_r($this->db->last_query());